# Как сделать окно приложения C# невидимым и не показывать в трее?

Tags: c#

Как сделать окно приложения C# невидимым и не показывать в трее?

Comment: Можно сделать консольное приложение и потом поменять Output Type на Windows Application и приложение будет безоконным.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Например в WPF, вы можете использовать `Window.Hide()` (`Show()` для отмены). Или `Window.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed` (`Visibility.Visible` для отмены). Или если вы вовсе не хотите показывать окно, уберите `StartupUri` в `App.xaml` (и поменяйте `ShutdownMode`, разумеется).

---

В WinForms аналогично помогает `Form.Visible = false; Form.ShowInTaskbar = false;`. Чтобы не показывать окно с самого начала, используйте `Application.Run()` без формы. Или вообще не запускайте `Application`, если вам не нужно будет показывать окно позже.

---

Консольные приложения бегут в консоли, так что если вам нужен такой эффект, лучше писать неконсольное приложение. Если очень надо, можно воспользоваться P/Invoke (одолжено [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3571628/276994)):

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static public extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static public extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    public const int SW_HIDE = 0;
    public const int SW_SHOW = 5;
}

var handle = NativeMethods.GetConsoleWindow();
NativeMethods.ShowWindow(handle, NativeMethods.SW_HIDE); // убрать
NativeMethods.ShowWindow(handle, NativeMethods.SW_SHOW); // вернуть назад
```

Но при этом всё равно окно появится сначала, а лишь потом скроется. (А если вас запустит в своей консоли другое консольное приложение, то вы спрячете его консоль, что ещё хуже, честно говоря.) Поэтому я бы не рекомендовал идти этим путём.

---

Если вы уже создали консольный проект, его можно легко превратить в windows-приложение, поменяв в свойствах проекта (вкладка Application) Output type с  Console Application на Windows Application.

Comment: а если консольное приложение?

Comment: @RakzinRoman: Консольное приложение бежит в консоли. Если вам нужно, чтобы её не было, не создавайте консольное приложение, создавайте оконное.

Comment: Не важно- winforms/wpf/console - нужно сделать просто, что б не высвечивалось окно

Comment: @RakzinRoman: Тогда создайте оконное приложение, но не давайте команду на показ окна.

Comment: using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("setup.exe");
        }
    }
}

Comment: @RakzinRoman: ? `namespace ConsoleApplication1` намекает на то, что это консольное приложение.

Comment: как, здесь просто не отобразить окно?. Нужно просто запустить другой файл через 2 секунды(но через бинарник, а не bat и др.)

Comment: Ну я ж написал — не создавайте консольное приложение. Создайте оконное с тем же исходным кодом.

Comment: @RakzinRoman: Зайдите в свойства проекта, поменяйте тип с Console Application на Windows Application.

Comment: я в консольном просто не вывел окно. А в вин формс объекта Window и потом Hide- не было. Я на c# не программировал года 3- уже забыл всё

Comment: @RakzinRoman: Не страшно, вспоминается быстро. Удачного вам повторного старта!